# Loading child record using record.load()

Tags: netsuite

I have two custom records which I've created in Netsuite having a parent-child relationship. Now I want to load child record using record.load() method in the RESTlet. When I use record.load(), it should load the child record by itself. But unfortunately, it does not. Please, Someone, tell me if I'm missing something.

```
 function _get(context) 
    {
        try
        {    
            if(context.singleRecord == 'true')
            {
                if(context.recordType == 'customrecord418')
                {
                    var project = record.load({
                        type: 'customrecord418',
                        id: context.id
                    });

                    if(context.forEdit == 'true')
                    {
                        log.debug({title:"project", details: project});
                        return {
                            id : project.getValue({fieldId: "id"}),
                            custrecord729 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord729"}),
                            custrecord734 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord734"}),
                            custrecord733 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord733"}),
                            custrecord732 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord732"}),
                            custrecord731 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord731"}),
                            custrecord730 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord730"}),
                            name : project.getValue({fieldId: "name"}),
                            projectPhases : null
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var projectPhases = [];
                            var numLines = project.getLineCount({
                                sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord739'
                            });

                            if (numLines > 0) 
                            {
                                for (var i = 0; i < numLines; i++) 
                                {
                                    projectPhases.push({
                                        id : project.getSublistValue({          
                                            sublistId : 'recmachcustrecord739',
                                            fieldId : 'id',
                                            line : i
                                        }),
                                        custrecord736 : project.getSublistValue({          
                                            sublistId : 'recmachcustrecord739',
                                            fieldId : 'custrecord736',
                                            line : i
                                        }),
                                        custrecord737 : project.getSublistValue({          
                                            sublistId : 'recmachcustrecord739',
                                            fieldId : 'custrecord737',
                                            line : i
                                        }),
                                        custrecord738 : project.getSublistValue({          
                                            sublistId : 'recmachcustrecord739',
                                            fieldId : 'custrecord738',
                                            line : i
                                        }),
                                        custrecord739 : project.getSublistValue({          
                                            sublistId : 'recmachcustrecord739',
                                            fieldId : 'custrecord739',
                                            line : i
                                        }),
                                        name : project.getSublistValue({          
                                            sublistId : 'recmachcustrecord739',
                                            fieldId : 'name',
                                            line : i
                                        })
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            return {
                                id : project.getValue({fieldId: "id"}),
                                custrecord729 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord729"}),
                                custrecord734 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord734"}),
                                custrecord733 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord733"}),
                                custrecord732 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord732"}),
                                custrecord731 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord731"}),
                                custrecord730 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord730"}),
                                name : project.getValue({fieldId: "name"}),
                                projectPhases : projectPhases
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var project = record.load({
                            type: 'customrecord421',
                            id: context.id
                        });
                        return {
                            id : project.getValue({fieldId: "id"}),
                            custrecord736 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord736"}),
                            custrecord737 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord737"}),
                            custrecord738 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord738"}),
                            custrecord739 : project.getValue({fieldId: "custrecord739"}),
                            name : project.getValue({fieldId: "name"})
                        }
                    }

            }    
            else
            {                        
                const projectList = [];
                var resultSet = search.load({
                    id: 'customsearch4629'
                })
                .run()
                .getRange({
                    start: 0,
                    end: 100
                });
                for(var i=0; i<resultSet.length; i++){
                    projectList.push({
                        id : resultSet[i].getValue({name: "id"}),
                        custrecord729 : resultSet[i].getValue({name: "custrecord729"}),
                        custrecord734 : resultSet[i].getValue({name: "custrecord734"}),
                        custrecord733 : resultSet[i].getValue({name: "custrecord733"}),
                        custrecord732 : resultSet[i].getText({name: "custrecord732"}),
                        custrecord731 : resultSet[i].getValue({name: "custrecord731"}),
                        custrecord730 : resultSet[i].getValue({name: "custrecord730"}),
                        name : resultSet[i].getValue({name: "name"})
                    });
                }
                return projectList;
            }
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            return String(ex.message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: krypton I've updated the question and added the code you can review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the Allow Child Record Editing preference in the child record.